# UIAlertController keeps segue from performing ("window is not equal to view’s window“)

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertcontroller

After adding a `UIAlertController` to my app to show a progress dialog while it's performing some set up, the segue isn't performing the switch to the second `ViewController` anymore (see question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56222145/2016165) - turns out the culprit isn't what I first thought it was, that's why I'm opening a new question).

So now I set up a test project using Swift 5, Xcode 10 and iOS 12 and I came across the same problem there too:

**Description:**

- ViewController1: Has a "Login" button that calls `onClickLoginButton`
- NavigationController: Connected to VC1 via "segue12" (I dragged from the yellow "ViewController" icon)
- ViewController2: I added the NC to it via "Embed in"; has a `UITableView`
- Clicking on the "Login" button displays a `UIAlertController` and should then perform the segue to VC2. Instead it only outputs a message in the console (see "console output" below) and keeps VC1 loaded.

**Storyboard:**

[image]

**ViewController1:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    var alert:UIAlertController!
    var alertMessage:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func onClickLoginButton(_ sender: Any) {
        setUpDialog()
    }

    private func setUpDialog() {
        alertMessage = "Logging in"
        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please wait", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue12", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("prepare 1->2a")
        let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        let tableVC = navVC?.viewControllers.first as! ViewController2
        tableVC.test = "Test!"
        print("prepare 1->2b")
    }
}
```

**ViewController2:**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var test:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
prepare 1->2a
prepare 1->2b
2019-05-21 13:09:16.981738+0200 SegueTest[3505:69382] <UIView: 0x7fc40fd0e790; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000dc3da0>>'s window is not equal to <UIAlertController: 0x7fc41180ba00>'s view's window!
```

Adding this to `prepare` (right before `print("prepare 1->2b")`) removes the dialog but it still outputs the message and doesn't switch to the second view:

```
alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What does the above message mean (what's causing it?) and how do I fix this test app, so it displays the dialog, then switches to ViewController2?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. If you want some `please wait` thing use a proper progress kinda view (there are many in cocoa pods) instead of AlertController. I don't thing ALertCOntrollers suppose to do that. If you are actually doing some loading before presenting the second view you should use some progress view with `completionhandler` so you can properly dismiss the progress view and open the second VC.

Comment: Unfortunately no proper progress view is built in. I want to use as few extra libraries as possible and there's no point to reinvent the wheel by creating my own view that is animated,... if AlertController is already a built in thing. You can use them without buttons (there's no error message/warning), you can change their text at runtime (do it from the main/ui thread!) and there's a built in function to dismiss it and do something else once it's gone (see the code Sh_Khan posted below). It might be a bit unconventional but it works and performance is good, so why not. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't present an alert and do a segue at the same time use  `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` to mook a waiting

```
private func setUpDialog() {
    alertMessage = "Logging in"
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please wait", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        self.alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue12", sender: self)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I actually need the `DispatchQueue`? I just tried it without in the test app and it still worked (isn't that what "completion" is for?). Do you also happen to know what the message means? Or is this one of these weird messages that don't say anything about the actual problem (like the "NSInvalidArgumentException" when an outlet is messed up)?

Comment: it'll work without `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` but you need it to give some time to the presented waiting alert before you dismiss it

Comment: Ah, I think I understand you mean. This is just the test app, so if my actual app presents the dialog, then does some stuff for a couple of seconds (like reading files, etc.) and only then dismisses it, the `DispatchQueue` won't be needed, right? Sorry, do you know what the message I posted in my question means?

Comment: if so make sure you do this is a background thread as not to block the appearance of the alert , also post full exception log to help

Comment: Yes, I will/currently am with half of my code. There's no exception, only a single message ("...'s window is not equal to ...'s view's window") and the app also doesn't crash. I have to test your answer with my real app, then I'll see the message is still output.

Comment: that means AlertController opens in a different window (on top of everything) than the main app window. and since you are not allowing it to animate properly before opening second VC I think you'll see that error. anyway don't use AlertController for this purpose. Use some progressview and wait for whatever the process to finish before opening second VC

Comment: @RJE In my actual app (this is just a test app to replicate the problem) the dialog opens without an error message and is displayed for a couple of seconds before it then closes with the switch, so the window it opens in is probably the right one. It doesn't output the message until I actually tell it to perform the segue. The dialog was dismissed just fine but the transition to the next view didn't work with it there. Unfortunately there's no built in ProgressDialog like in Android, an AlertController (with `completion`) is the only thing coming remotely close without using extra libraries.